# Ensuring memorization doesn't happen between between train and test sets in a Machine Learning model

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, named-entity-recognition

Recently, contractors developed an NER solution for us which extracts relevant drugs out of pharmaceutical policies (drugs that the policy was describing coverage criteria for). Part of their process was to go through the training set, and replace drugs ("Tylenol", etc) that also appeared in the test set, in order to ensure that the model was learning about the context of the drug, rather than memorizing the drug name (ex. showing up in sentences like "Tylenol is covered under the following circumstances...").

My question is, if we have new test data added, and we want to reevaluate the model, would it make sense to substitute words in the test set to make sure that they don't appear in the previous training set, or should we re-substitute the words in the training set, retrain the model, and reevaluate on the new test data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**How-To Training Data**

If you have input values in your data that you do not want to learn from, e.g. because you do not have these values during deployment. Or you feel like this could bias the model - definitely get rid of this information - and clean your data. Also when you feel like drug names might be an issue not only remove the ones you also try to predict, but instead remove all drug names (with a dictionary or something). This might also prevent later substitutions and repetitive data cleaning activities - which usually are a pain.

**How-To Test Data**

Another thing is how you want your test and validation data to be looking like. And a best practice is to have them drawn from the same distribution as your training data - this means, all preprocessing steps you are doing on your training data also has to be done on your validation and test data. So purely tinkering with your test-data will skew your results or make your model act crazy.

That being said, in case you want to see how good your model performs under uncertainty that is a complete different story.

Answer (score 0):

#### Replacing drugs in the new test data that appear in the training data

First, I would recommend testing the model on the new test data, both with and without replacement of drug names that appeared in the original training data. If the model does better without replacement than with replacement, it may mean that it has memorized some drug names from the original training data. You could verify this by checking whether the advantage came from drugs that were not replaced in the training data, because they did not appear in the original test data.

##### Aside about substitution method

Keep in mind that details of the substitution method may affect the results, depending on how the model works. For instance, the model may be able to learn particular arrangements of letters within a word (e.g., learning that ending in “-ol” or “-azone” indicates a drug name). As a result, if the replacement drug names do not reflect the real-world (i.e. deployment) statistics of how letter clusters are distributed within drug names, then you may still be getting some degree of memorization even with the substitution method. This form of memorization is not necessarily bad (as drug names tend to have unique lexicographic structures), but you want to make sure that your substitutions do not favor some patterns over others. This could require drawing your substitutions in a balanced manner from a list of all existing drug names (which may not be practical). Additionally, even this rigorous substitution method assumes that newly developed drugs that you may want to identify in the future will stick to the lexicographic naming conventions/trends of current drugs.

#### Replacing drugs in the training set that appear in the new test set and retraining

You also mention the possibility of retraining the model after redoing the substitutions for drugs that appear in the new data set. This may be appropriate if your goal is to compare performance based on some other difference between the two test data sets (e.g., different types of documents). If this is your aim, I would recommend undoing all of the original substitutions made by the contractors in the training data, then following the same substitution procedures but only for the drugs in the new test data set. This will ensure that the results of the two model evaluations on the two different test sets are comparable. Before going down this route you should also consider how costly it would be to retrain the model.

Comment: But specifically for substitution, does it make sense to replace drugs in the test set if they appear in the training set as well? Or does it only make sense to replace drug in the training set if they appear in the test set?

Comment: Sorry @ArthurLee, I believe I missed the crux of your question in my original answer. I’ve edited to more directly address the pros and cons of the two options you propose.

Comment: @ArthurLee see the second answer for clarification.